# Filter Columns based the condition of a Row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following Matrix in SSRS 2008 R2:

[image]

What I would like to do is only show columns where the "FTE" row has a value. (Marked with red circles).  I've tried the filter and show/hide options based on expressions in the Column Properties, but I can't figure out how to only reference the rows when "category"="FTE".  My data looks like this:

```
tblPhysicians 
employee_id    last_name    ...
102341145      Smith
123252252      Jones

tblPhysiciansMetrics
id      fy     period     division_name      category_name     employee_id
123     2014   1          Allergy            Overhead          123456
124     2014   1          Allergy            Salary            125223
125     2014   1          Allergy            FTE               1.0


query
SELECT * FROM
tblPhysicians
INNER JOIN tblPhysicianMetrics
   ON tblPhysicians.employee_id = tblPhysicianMetrics.employee_id
WHERE
   tblPhysicianMetrics.division_name = @division_name
   AND tblPhysicianMetrics.fy = @fy
   AND tblPhysicianMetrics.period = @period
```

Notice that the rows in my Matrix is just the category_name, so I can't just hide when category_name = "FTE", that's not really what I want.  What I really need is some way of saying, "For rows where category_name = "FTE", if the value is not set, don't show that column".  Is this possible?

An alternative would be to not even get those in the query, but as with the filtering of the matrix, if I simply add "AND tblPhysiciansMetrix.category_name = 'FTE'" to the WHERE clause, my entire data set is reduced to only those records where category_name is FTE.

Any help is much appreciated!

Update: added definition of Matrix to help:

[image]

Comment: Would an 
AND 
((category_name = 'FTE' and employee_id is not null) OR category_name <> 'FTE')
type of logic work?  With all of the column and row headers blurred i'm guessing at part of the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the column visibility with an expression that checks all underlying data in the column for the *FTE* category.

I have a simple dataset:

[image]

And a simple matrix based on this:

[image]

Which looks exactly as you expect:

[image]

So in the above example, we want the *Brown* column to be hidden. To do this, use an expression like this for the **Column Visibility**:

```
=IIf(Sum(IIf(Fields!category_name.Value = "FTE", 1, 0), "last_name") > 0
  , False
  , True)
```

This is effectively counting all the fields in the column (determined by the `last_name` scope parameter in the `Sum` expression) - if this is > 0 show the column. Works as required:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @russds, did this help at all? Am I understanding your requirements correctly?

Answer (score 0):

*CAVEAT* I'm not 100% sure how you are grouping this data in the matrix. It isn't 100% clear from your description. Let me know why this doesn't work (if it doesn't and I'll update my answer accordingly.

I've replaced the column employee_id with the name value for my answer, to keep my explanation simple.

Add this nested IIF() to the visibility property of your Matrix's column.

```
 =IIF(Fields!category_Name.Value="FTE" ,IIF( Fields!value.Value >= 0, True,False),false)
```

It will check both the value of the the category and the 'FTE' in that row's cell.

Comment: Thanks you.  I added "=IIF(Fields!category_name.Value="FTE", IIF(Fields!amount.Value >=0, True, False), false)" to the column properties ("amount") is the name of the field with the value, but report is still showing those columns.  I'll update my question with a screen shot of my matrix definition.